# Flutter: How to create a folder at the root of the directory, i.e, not under any directory

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart

I am developing a file based application through flutter.

I can create a folder through `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` which gives the path to write files. But it cannot be seen in the `files Explorer`

I then created the folder through `getExternalStorageDirectory()` , which can be seen in the `files explorer`. But I want it to be created in the root.

You may have seen whatsapp folder in the root directory. I also want the same thing. I have tried the following:

```
Directory('FolderName').create()
```

But it gives the error saying 'read only os '

Is there a way to do it through flutter ?

Comment: You requested permission to read storage on Android?

Comment: yes. Both on manifest as well as through permission_handler. I am able to create the folders in the app's directory, but not on the root

Comment: You mead root as `/` or root as directory where storing `Download`, `Documents` and etc. folders?

Comment: I mean first Directory in external storage like whatsapp

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way:

```
String folderName = "My New Downloads";
var path = "storage/emulated/0/$folderName";
await  new Directory(path).create();
```

Comment: It is a long back project and I cannot try it now. Thankyou anyway

Comment: From Android 11 and higher, you can't make your own folders here, you need to write to Documents or DCIM, etc..